# Python(3), Loop over tuple and use string format to display

Tags: python, tuples, string-formatting

My homework assignment is to Loop over ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4)) and use string formatting to display this tuple as:

```
1 = 1 x 1  
4 = 2 x 2
156 = 12 x 13 
16 = 4 x 4
```

while also preserving the spacing.

What I have so far:

```
d = ((1,1), (2,2), (12,13), (4,4))
for a, b in d:
    print("{0} = {1}".format(a* b, d))
```

Which gives me:

```
1 = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4))
4 = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4))
156 = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4))
16 = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4))
```

So it seems to me that I am getting close. But I have run out of ideas to get the right side of the equation into the correct format.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = ((1,1), (2,2), (12,13), (4,4))
for a, b in d:
    print("{0} = {1} x {2}".format(a* b, a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

On the right side of the equation you want to print the content of variable `a`, then the character `x` and then the content of variable `b`.